# Drawing x-y plot with rhombus width and height controlled by xError and yError in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I posted a recent post about controlling x-y plots as two Normal curves and have since realised I was making things too complicated.  I have since managed to plot it as ellipse's but this slightly over estimates the error; which ideally could be plotted as rhombus.

The code I have to date is:

```
plot(c(-5,10), c(-5,5),  xlab = expression(Age), ylab = expression(value), type="n")
draw.ellipse(Age, value, a=Age_error, b=value_error, col="grey70")
```

Which plots: 
[image: Ellipse figure]

Is there someway to replace the ellipse with a rhombus whose height is controlled by 2x value_error and width by 2x age_error?

My data frame is below

```
  structure(list(Age = c(1L, 2L, 4L), value = c(3, -2, 0.01), Age_error = c(2, 
  1.4, 3), value_error = c(0.5, 1, 2.1)), .Names = c("Age", "value", 
  "Age_error", "value_error"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -3L))
```

Many thanks

Comment: Where does `draw.ellipse` come from?

Comment: I'm guessing you just want to use `polygon` to create a `draw.rhombus` function that connects the four extreme points? Yes?

Comment: Yes - something like that would be great.  I can work out one rhombus (I think); but was struggling for multiple.  Some of my plots have ~60 x-y pairs.

Comment: Just use a loop or one of the apply/plyr functions - the `draw.ellipse` function does exactly that, calling its `draw1ellipse` function.

Comment: Thanks.  Will try.  I have made one rhombus, but needed a whole new dataframe with 2 columns and 4 rows.  Not quite sure how to convert all my x-y pairs into a sutiable setup.  I'll work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `my.symbols` and `ms.polygon` functions in the TeachingDemos package to draw the rhombuses:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
plot(c(-5,10), c(-5,5),  xlab = expression(Age), ylab = expression(value), 
    type="n")
my.symbols( Age, value, ms.polygon, n=4, xsize=2*Age_error, 
    ysize=2*value_error, linesfun=polygon, col='grey' )
```

Leave out `linesfun` and `col` if you don't want the rhombuses filled.